# Getting unexpected token into ternary operator

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I want to do a simple ternary operation like:

```
   progressToBackCheckMedianString = $"{newLine} Medians {(medianInProgressFormattedTime != string.Empty ? {newLine} {medianInProgressFormattedTime}{newLine} : string.Empty)}" ;
```

But I'm getting

> Unexpected token '{'

and  `{(medianInProgressFormattedTime != string.Empty ?` is marked in red with this error. What I'm doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), which support c# version higher than 6.0

> {interpolatedExpression}

the big parentheses have special mean in the syntax.

Your `newLine` seem like a string value.

Remove the `{` and `}` between `newLine` and use `+` to connect string value, because the outer already use big parentheses.

I would use

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty
```

check string value instead of

```
medianInProgressFormattedTime != string.Empty
```

because `medianInProgressFormattedTime` possible be `NULL`.

```
string progressToBackCheckMedianString = $"{newLine} Medians{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(medianInProgressFormattedTime) ? newLine + medianInProgressFormattedTime + newLine : string.Empty)}";
```

[c# Test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbqQa7)

Answer (score 0):

Add the string quotation around `{newLine} {medianInProgressFormattedTime}{newLine}`

```
progressToBackCheckMedianString = $"{newLine} Medians {(medianInProgressFormattedTime != string.Empty ? $"{newLine} {medianInProgressFormattedTime}{newLine}" : string.Empty)}";
```